# SharePoint - what type is Number field

Tags: sharepoint, spfield

I have a Field, that has `Type="Number"`. What type of variables can I assign to it?
Will the field support `float` or `double`?

```
oListItem["numberField"] = data;
```

What type can `data` be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All values that's string representation can be parsed as double, since SharePoint converts the input value to a string:

```
case SPFieldType.Number:
case SPFieldType.Currency:
  str1 = Convert.ToString(value, (IFormatProvider) CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  break;
```

(from *SPListItem.SetValue(...)*)

You should be fine with `string`, `int`, `double`, etc.